# Copy Rotation not working, but was working initially

Tags: constraints, rigify

[image]

So I was making some changes to my rig, with some constraints applied to some bones. After regenerating it, for some reason, the constraint for curling the fingers stopped working. The screenshot I added is the constraint on the generated rig for the fingers. That constraint was already working before, and I didn't change it before regenerating. What could be the reason this thing stopped working?

[image]

Comment: It is because you regenerated the rig, replacing your generated rig and thus losing changes you had made to it.  If you need changes to persist through regeneration, you need to making edits to the metarig.  Presumably, this is Rigify (although it would be good to specify that in the question.)  You can see more details on how metarigs can be edited for Rigify at https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/metarigs.html .  In general, if you want to edit a rig to do exactly what you want, you probably don't want Rigify, you want to make your own rig.

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about? All the changes I made were applied to metarig before before I regenerated the rig. And I mentioned it worked before, right? I used the term rig because I would presume that that's immediately understood as relating to rigify by a blender forum. "Presumably. this is rigify"? Have you looked at the tags I used? And what's the use of rigify if it can't even handle a few additional constraints?